# Paypal encrypted button doesn't work in sandbox but works in official page

Tags: button, paypal, encryption

I'm using a python script to encrypt my buttons.

I uploaded my certificate to Paypal and downloaded their public key.

When I sign a button and click on it with the link :

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```

It works.

But now, if I **JUST** change the url to the sandbox, with the same others values :

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```

It doesn't work, I got this message :

```
Error Detected
    We were unable to decrypt the certificate id.
```

Is there something am I missing? I can't find why this doesn't work!

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate will be tied to:

`https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`

If you want to test in the sandbox you'll need a **2<sup>nd</sup>** certificate tied to:

`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`

They're different URLs - PayPal is correct in reporting an error.

Comment: Oh can I specify where the certificate belongs to which url? There is no mention of sandbox or not in "Website Payment Certificates" part of my profile in Paypal.

Comment: @cx42net - I would hope so - but I don't know the exact procedure with PayPal. The point of a certificate is to reassure the customer that the site is legit. If you could use the certificate from one site on another that would defeat the object.

Comment: Well in fact you are right, after a long search, what I needed to do is connect to the sandbox site of paypal and do the same as what I did with my cert in the official website. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error also occurs when you use the PayPal's production pem file (paypal_cert_pem.txt) sandbox in your testing, or vice versa.  Sandbox and Live have different files so make sure you use the right one.